# Reindexing products overwriting my custom url-key feature

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, reindex

I am importing products through soap api and while importing i am concatenating url_key for products with product name and sku.i am doing this because i have some products which has same name. so though product has same name i am concatenating products name and sku to make it unique.products are importing fine with the url key concatenating with the name and sku

Now the problem is whenever i am re-indexing this feature of url key concatenating with the products and sku is gone.how can i maintain this my custom feature.

My code is

```
$client->catalogProductCreate($session, 'simple', $set, $sku, array(
    'name' => $name,
    'description' => $row["QDS_DESCRIPTION"],
    'short_description' => $row["QDS_DESCRIPTION"],
    'weight' => '1',
    'status' => $status,
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => $price,
    'tax_class_id' => 0,
    'stock_data' => $stock_data,
    'additional_attributes' => array(
        'single_data' => array(
            array('key' => 'url_key', 'value' => $url_key),
    ),
)
```

Comment: How are you defining the URL key? Are you setting it as part of the vanilla Magento SOAP API for products?

Comment: i had updated the code.

Comment: So when you run the API call the `url_key` is set and saved correctly on the product? It only disappears when you reindex? If that's the case, can you run `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'url_key'` to see if you have two URL key attributes in your DB?

Comment: Also be aware that it looks like you're setting data at the admin level, so if you set your product has a URL key defined already at a store level, it will probably be used instead of your admin level URL key when reindexing happens. Even if this is not the case, it's worth inspecting the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table for the values that get set in the database for that attribute ID after your SOAP import, then compare again after you reindex.